# Big-IP F5 irule to change uri

Tags: f5, big-ip, irule

Is there a way to change a URI without a redirect. I want to change the following URL

```
https://example.com//q//w//et
```

to

```
https://example.com/q/w/et
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what iRules are made for.

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
   if { [HTTP::uri] equals "/q//w//et" } {
      HTTP::uri "/q/w/et"
   }
}
```

Have a look here:

https://devcentral.f5.com/s/question/0D51T00006j2rZDSAY/replace-part-of-uri